# On finding the limits of sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I have been going over the textbook on differential and integral calculus by Courant and I am currently on the chapter 5, i.e. “The concept of the limit of a sequence” and there is something I cannot quite understand.
I have gone over the examples the author provides, and I notice that when dealing with limits involving rational fractions, instead of dividing both the numerator and the denominator by the highest degree term of n (e.g. 2n², 4n, 7n³ etc.), he approaches it from the perspective of inequalities and transformations of the following kind: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n+1} \right)$$
At the end of this chapter, there are exercises also involving limits of rational functions of an integral variable (or just limits of expressions which can be solved by just getting rid of the highest order term both in the numerator and denominator). Now I am not sure whether I am allowed to find those limits by, once again, resorting to dividing the numerator and denominator. Why can’t I just do this for limits of the following sort: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3 + 5n}{n^2 + n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1 + \frac{5}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}} = \infty $$ ?
Am I supposed to solve them by factoring? If yes, and nothing can be taken for granted (so much for mathematical rigour), why does the author take, for example, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} = 0 $$ for granted? Why cannot I perform the transformations I mentioned above and regard them as being obvious?
Keep in mind that it was but the introduction to the concept and no arithmetic operations with limits were introduced.

Basically, the question is what I can take for granted and what I cannot.

Comment: Depends on your idea of mathematics. Is it a game played according to some fixed rules? Is it learning to solve problems using learned results? Is it something else? What do you think?

Comment: You can take for granted theorems you have proved before, and examples which you may have completely (i.e with proof) worked out before (I guess you could also call these 'theorems'), but you of course can't take for granted things you haven't proven yet, that's like writing an exam when you already have the solution key. Several times, there are different ways of solving problems, but the intermediate steps may need to be tailored so that you invoke only what you've already proven.

Comment: From what little I can see of the book on-line, Courant is giving an introduction to Real Analysis based on hyperreals. This is not the definition of limits that you learned in Calculus I (assuming you even learned an actual definition for limits in the first place - many Calc I courses skip it for an intuitive approach). He is rebuilding the concept from scratch. You are not free to use results developed under a different set of definitions here. For rigour, you can only use the concepts built in this system to show things in this system.